# Changing image within div when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Spent a couple of days on this now and need some guidance. I have a toggle with an image within the div. Basically when the div is clicked the image within it should change to a different image.

Here is a link to the jsfiddle, so you can see the image at the top which should change once the whole toggle area is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/VLe8g/

Also here is the code

HTML

```
<div class="toggle-wrap">
  <div class="trigger">
    <div class="one-third"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></div>
    <div class="two-thirds column-last">This is where the heading goes <br />
      This is where the description goes<br />
      <a href="#">Toggle Open</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="toggle-container">
    <div class="one-third">First column This is where the heading goes This is where the heading goes</div>
    <div class="one-third">Second column This is where the heading goes This is where the heading goes</div>
    <div class="one-third column-last">Third column This is where the heading goes This is     where the heading goes</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.toggle-wrap {
        float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.trigger {}

.trigger a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1D1D1B;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0s; 
    -moz-transition-duration: 0s; 
    -o-transition-duration: 0s; 
    background: url(tobeadded) no-repeat right 15px #F3F3F3;
 }

.trigger.active a { 
    background: url(tobeadded) no-repeat right -20px #F3F3F3;
}

.toggle-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}

.one-third, .two-thirds {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4%;
}

.one-third {
    width: 30.66%;  
} 

.two-thirds {
        width: 64%; 
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(".toggle-container").hide(); 
        $(".trigger").toggle(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active");
        }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".toggle-container").slideToggle();
    });
```

Hope you guys can help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/bqs7Z/)**

Try this:

```
$(".toggle-container").hide();
$(".trigger").toggle(function () {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".trigger").find('img').prop('src', 'http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png');
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(".trigger").find('img').prop('src', 'http://placehold.it/200x200');
});
$(".trigger").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".toggle-container").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/400x400");
```

will change the image from a 200x200 to a 400x400. You can add a class to both of them (i.e. class=small, class=big) which jQuery can use to identify which one is currently being displayed and toggle between them.

Answer (score 0):

assign an id to image tag like i did

```
<img id="test" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
```

and use the following code:

```
$(".toggle-container").hide(); 
    $(".trigger").toggle(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $('#test').attr('src','http://placehold.it/200x200');
        }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
            $('#test').attr('src','https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s200x200/851558_201013993381868_2094147002_n.png');
    });
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".toggle-container").slideToggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the *id* attribute to your **img**, and then change the *src* attribute every time the toggle handler is executed.
The **img** definition should something like this:

```
<img id="myImage" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
```

and your toggle handler should look like this:

```
$(".trigger").toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#myImage").attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/some_other_image');
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $("#myImage").attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/200x200');
});
```